# Google Sheets Switch

Tags: google-sheets

I'm not sure where to go with this but some time ago, we had some assistance setting up a google sheet for our community sports club.  An arrayformula was used with switch and up until the end of March all was working.  Having done some searches, it appears google may have made changes to Switch and other users reporting similar issues.

In summary, using google forms, players were entered confirming male or female and date of birth. Using a secondary tab, the age group was defined as follows:

```
Gender      Group   Date From   Date To
Male/Female U06s    01/09/2014  31/08/2015
Male/Female U07s    01/09/2013  31/08/2014
Male/Female U08s    01/09/2012  31/08/2013
Male/Female U09s    01/09/2011  31/08/2012
Male/Female U10s    01/09/2010  31/08/2011
Male/Female U11s    01/09/2009  31/08/2010
Male    U12s    01/09/2008  31/08/2009
Male    U13s    01/09/2007  31/08/2008
Male    U14s    01/09/2006  31/08/2007
Male    U15s    01/09/2005  31/08/2006
Male    U16s    01/09/2004  31/08/2005
Male    U17s    01/09/2003  31/08/2004
Male    U18s    01/09/2002  31/08/2003
Female  G13s    01/09/2007  31/08/2009
Female  G15s    01/09/2005  31/08/2007
Female  G18s    01/09/2002  31/08/2005
Male/Female Delete
```

On the responses page, the below formula was used to define what age group each players was in.  Now that no longer works and we get #value with error message "Switch has mismatched range siezes.  Expected forw count:1" etc.

Formula is:

=ARRAYFORMULA({"Group";IF(A2:A="",,If(H:H="",,SWITCH(I:I,"Male",VLOOKUP(H:H,SORT({GroupInfo!C2:C18*({GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male"}+{GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male/Female"}),GroupInfo!B2:B18},1,1),2,1),"Female",VLOOKUP(H:H,SORT({GroupInfo!C2:C18*({GroupInfo!A2:A18="Female"}+{GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male/Female"}),GroupInfo!B2:B18},1,1),2,1))))})

Any suggestions or guidance on where I can get assistnace?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try the IFS formula instead of the SWITCH

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Group";IF(A2:A="",,If(H:H="",,
IFS(I:I="Male",
VLOOKUP(H:H,SORT({GroupInfo!C2:C18*({GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male"}+{GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male/Female"}),GroupInfo!B2:B18},1,1),2,1),
I:I="Female",
VLOOKUP(H:H,SORT({GroupInfo!C2:C18*({GroupInfo!A2:A18="Female"}+{GroupInfo!A2:A18="Male/Female"}),GroupInfo!B2:B18},1,1),2,1))
))})
```

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/google-sheets-switch-formula-how-to-and-compare-it-with-if-and-ifs/

Here are examples of how this can be done

Comment: Thank you so much Sergey... i had to change the formula slightly to start on row 2 but all works perfectly!!! THank you.